# How to write a PL/SQL procedure with x input parameters and input/ouput of x parameters combined

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have to make a procedure that will create me autonomously a ***STUDENT_ID*** with the input parameters as *Name, Surname, Gender, Date_Birth, State*.

**Example :**

- Name: John
- Surname: Smith
- Gender: M
- Birth Date: 17/05/1996
- state: California

**Output:**

```
STUDENT_ID is : JHN-STH-M-17596-CLFN
```

*I put "-" to make it see better in the question but in the output it should be JHNSTHM17596CLFN*

I have made 5 separate procedures that will calculate name, surname ecc..
I want to write a procedure that will calculate the ***STUDENT_ID*** using the procedures I made (in order) , and also have an "input" parameter and input/output "student" that will "print" the ***STUDENT_ID***

```
procedure  student_id     (surname in varchar2,
                           name in varchar2,
                           gender in varchar2,
                           date_birth in varchar2,
                           state in varchar2) is
begin

....


dbms_output.put_line ('Student_ID is :');
```

*This code is "supposed" to be the input parameter, I don't know if its written correctly*

Comment: I don't understand the expected output.  where does the H come from?  Also to convert "California" to "CLFN" (Which is a state), you would either have to create a lookup table, or have a CASE expression for every state.

Comment: @OldProgrammer H comes from joHn (name, I have made a procedure to calculate the name, where it will extract me only the first 3 consonant) , "CLFN" was an example (a bad one)  of the input and the expected output, I have a procedure and a city table that I get reference from. All I want is an example of how I should write the procedure to calculate the student_id , included all the other procedures I have made to calculate name,surname ecc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks as if

- you should "convert" **procedures** that calculate every part of the `STUDENT_ID` into **functions**

  - Why? Because - as it is now - procedures have to have an OUT parameter so that they could return what they calculated. And that's nothing but a function
- pass pieces of information to each of them
- get the result
- **concatenate** result pieces into the final `STUDENT_ID` values

Something like this:

```
function f_name (par_name in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  retval varchar2(20);
begin
  retval := whatever code you have to find it
  return retval;
end;

function f_surname (par_surname in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  retval varchar2(20);
begin
  retval := whatever code you have to find it
  return retval;
end;

etc.

procedure student_id (par_surname in varchar2, par_name in varchar2, ...)
is
  l_student_id varchar2(30);
begin
  l_student_id := f_name   (par_name)    ||'-'||
                  f_surname(par_surname) ||'-'||
                  f_gender (par_gender)  ||'-'||
                  ...
                  f_state  (par_state);
                  
  dbms_output.put_line('Student_ID is: ' || l_student_id);
end;
```

Finally, as all those functions and procedure deal with the same problem, it would be nice to put them all into a **package**.