# Why do I get an error in calling this procedure?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have a procedure named student_id

```
 procedure student_id ( v_surname  in varchar2,  
                        v_name in varchar2,  
                        v_date_birth in varchar2,
                        v_gender in varchar2,
                        v_state in varchar2)  is l_student_id varchar2;
 begin
 l_student_id :=  par_surname(v_surname)       ||'-'||
                  par_name(v_name)             ||'-'||
                  par_date_birht(v_date_birth) ||'-'||
                  par_gender(v_gender)         ||'-'||
                  par_state(v_state);
 dbms_output.put_line('Student ID :  ' ||  l_student_id);
end student_id;
```

What my  expected output should be after I will write the values :

(Student ID : JOHN-SMITH-170692-M-CALIFORNIA)

Error I get:

```
Error with beginning of line: 291  in the command -
procedure cod_fiscale ( v_surname  in varchar2,
Report error -
unknown command   

Error with beginning of line : 292 in the command -
                        v_name  in varchar2,
Report error -
unknown command  

Error with beginning of line : 293 in the command -
                        v_date_birth  in varchar2,
Report error -
unknown command    

Error with beginning of line : 294 in the command -
                        v_gender  in varchar2,
Report error -
unknown command    

SP2-0044:to get the list of known commands, enter HELP
and enter EXIT to exit.
Error with beginning of line : 295 in the command -
                        v_state  in varchar2) is l_student_id varchar2;
Report error -
unknown command    

Error with beginning of line : 296 in the command -
begin
 l_student_id :=  par_surname(v_surname)       ||'-'||
                  par_name(v_name)             ||'-'||
                  par_date_birht(v_date_birth) ||'-'||
                  par_gender(v_gender)         ||'-'||
                  par_state(v_state);
 dbms_output.put_line('Student ID :  ' ||  l_student_id);
end student_id;
Report error -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 25:
PLS-00103: Found symbol   "" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

*I roughly translated the error I got because it was in another language.*

*Note: This isn't a standalone procedure, this code is related to my previous question.

Found at :[How to write a PL/SQL procedure with x input parameters and input/ouput of x parameters combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372067/how-to-write-a-pl-sql-procedure-with-x-input-parameters-and-input-ouput-of-x-par)*

What is my error here? What is the cause of the error?

Comment: If this is a standalone procedure, you need to add a `CREATE` (or, more likely, a `CREATE OR REPLACE`) in front of the word `PROCEDURE`

Comment: I forgot to mention it, it isnt a standalone procedure. There are 5 functions and this procedure "unite" the 5 functions. Too see better, I will link my previous question that is related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372067/how-to-write-a-pl-sql-procedure-with-x-input-parameters-and-input-ouput-of-x-par

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your package, I can spot one issue:

```
procedure student_id ( v_surname  in varchar2,  
                        v_name in varchar2,  
                        v_date_birth in varchar2,
                        v_gender in varchar2,
                        v_state in varchar2)  is
  l_student_id varchar2; -- you need to declare the length of your variable
begin
  ...
```

You've declared the type of your variable, but you haven't said how long it needs to be. It should be something like:

```
l_student_id varchar2(400);
```

although you should change the 400 to the right value for the expected maximum length of the values that will be stored in that variable.

Comment: I also get an error after begin, I get this:

Errore(398,23): PLS-00103:Found symbol  "name" instead of i:  . ( * %    & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset Il simbolo "." it is substituted to permit name to continue(?) 

I roughly translated it, I get that error for all the next parameters( surname,gender, ecc)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to provide the full package listing. I can't take what you've provided and debug it myself, because there isn't enough context available. The new issue might lie elsewhere in your package.